# set Keyboard  coordination: How to set the keyboard x,y co ordination

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

I have list of products which have `EditText` in `TableLayout`.

I want Keyboard in right/left of `EditText` and it needs to be containing 0-9 ,.(dot) ,Delete,and Done.Don't need other keys.

Each time when the user click `EditText`, it will show key pad to right of `EditText` (trigger/onClickListner).

**Currently I did Like this:**

[image]

How we can implement.

**And normal list is :**

[image]

I want keypad right of /left of text-box.Keyboard may be user define/predefine.How we can implement these.
I have created one keyboard.Its always display the bottom of the screen. I need right of textbox or left.

`How can i set the keyboard coordination`. Please tell me...

I don't have any idea on how to do this. I want to implement this.

My created keyboard width & high is too small than default.
Please advice me / guide me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
How can i set the keyboard coordination.
```

If you are using your custom Keyboard you `Can't locate it at your desired position`. By **Default** it will appears at the **Bottom** only.

So you can try with [Custom Pop up window](http://www.mobilemancer.com/2011/01/08/popup-window-in-android/) , [Another Post](http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/04/animated-customized-popup-transparent.html)   for your requirement.

You can try with [Quick Action Dialog](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) for you requirement

Also check this [Touch Calculator Source](http://mmlearningresources.blogspot.com/2011/02/introduction-to-android-development.html) for you reference.